# System slow and apps not working on Lineage OS 14.1

Tags: lineageos

Recently I updated my Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2 (GTS7582) from CM 13.1 to Lineage OS 14.1 using the unofficial build I found [here](http://www.lineageosrom.com/2017/01/download-lineage-os-Galaxy-S-Duos-2.html). It ran smoothly at the beginning and I took to it immediately. However, after installing some apps, I'm experiencing serious speed issues on my phone. Newly installed apps don't even open; if they do, they just stop working and quit. I observed that Lineage is using the same amount of RAM that CM used to use... so I'm guessing the problem is with the ROM I used and not my phone. If anyone knows of a way to speed up my phone, please advise me. If not, can you suggest another ROM that is lighter and more stable. My key requirement is that it should support extending main memory to the SD card, so that the SD card can be used as main memory. This was my primary reason for upgrading to Lineage in the first place, because my phone doesn't have much in the way of internal storage. It should also, ideally, look as good as Lineage.

Thanks :D

Comment: Don't expect an old, outdated phone to always run new versions of Android smoothly, there's always a threshold to the hardware's capabilities. That said, going to the respective ROM thread on XDA will serve you better than here.

Comment: Oh... @AndyYan I've replaced it with CM 13. and it's running fine. I'm keeping my fingers crossed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issues on OnePlus 2, but I have tried custom kernels which caused battery life issues. I tried to modify the cpu settings with Kernel Auditor (from google play, requires at least root). It did help a lot but somehow the app intersects with wifi hotspot, so it wasn't a solution.

Today I found a risk free option worth trying:
http://www.androidbeat.com/2017/03/how-to-stop-android-apps-killed-marshmallow-nougat/

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).